# Gradle works with proxy settings but Gradle-wrapper does not. Why?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle 5.0 installation on windows 10. I use a proxy, so I put the proxy information into gradle.properties in the bin subdirectory of the gradle installation:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=myproxyserver
systemProp.http.proxyPort=myport
systemProp.http.proxyUser=myuser
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=mypassword

systemProp.https.proxyHost=myproxyserver
systemProp.https.proxyPort=myport
systemProp.https.proxyUser=myuser
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=mypassword
```

I created a simple java project with build.gradle. Executing `gradle build` works.
However executing `./gradlew build` tries to download the gradle zip file as in the gradle-wrapper.properties and generates an exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

So I put the above proxy settings at the beginning of the gradle-wrapper.properties file. However gradlew build still generates the same exception.

I checked other posts and could not find a solution for this particular problem. Could you help me make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste your question's code in a new file inside your root project named "[gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)".
As an alternative, you can also add it inside your buildscript, as described in the relevant [section](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) of the gradle docs.

The file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` contains [info](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) about the wrapper itself and it is different from the file `gradle.properties` in your project's root folder. If you have modified that it would be best to return it to its original state.

Comment: Thank you tryman! Copying gradle.properties into the root directory of the project did it!